# ¿Cómo mostrar el mes en texto en java?

Tags: java, date

Tengo lo siguiente y me pinta el mes pero en numero, y yo lo quiero mostrar en texto(Enero, Febrero, etc.)
Como puedo mostrarlo en texto?

```
private int annio;
private int mes;
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
public void obtenerMesAño() {
   annio = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mes = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Si utilizas **Java 8** puedes utilizar las clases del package [time](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/java/paquete-java-time-2390472-esa.html) para obtener el nombre del mes. Es muy sencillo, solo necesitas dos lineas.

```
// Obtienes el mes actual
Month mes = LocalDate.now().getMonth();

// Obtienes el nombre del mes
String nombre = mes.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, new Locale("es", "ES"));
```

El único detalle es que el nombre del mes te lo da en minúscula, pero eso no es mucho problema, con el siguiente bloque de código fácilmente conviertes la primera letra del mes en mayúscula.

```
// Convierte a mayúscula la primera letra del nombre.
String primeraLetra = nombre.substring(0,1);
String mayuscula = primeraLetra.toUpperCase();
String demasLetras = nombre.substring(1, nombre.length());
nombre = mayuscula + demasLetras;

System.out.println(nombre);
```

Recuerda importar las librerías necesarias.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplificando el asunto podrias utilizar un arreglo con los meses del año, es la forma más viable. Convierte el mes en tipo  `String`.

```
private int annio;
private String mes;
String MES[] = {"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
public void obtenerMesAño() {
   annio = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mes = MES[c1.get(Calendar.MONTH)];

}
```

Comment: excelente, gracias!

Comment: Excelente, lejos la mejor solución.

Answer (score 2):

puedes usar un switch.

```
String mesString;
switch (mes) {
        case 1:  mesString = "Enero";
                 break;
        case 2:  mesString  = "Febrero";
                 break;
        case 3:  mesString = "Marzo";
                 break;
        case 4:  mesString = "Abril";
                 break;
        case 5:  mesString = "Mayo";
                 break;
        case 6:  mesString = "Junio";
                 break;
        case 7:  mesString = "Julio";
                 break;
        case 8:  mesString = "Agosto";
                 break;
        case 9:  mesString = "Septiembre";
                 break;
        case 10: mesString = "Octubre";
                 break;
        case 11: mesString = "Noviembre";
                 break;
        case 12: mesString = "Diciembre";
                 break;
        default: mesString = "Invalid month";
                 break;
        }
        System.out.println(mesString);
```

De esta forma, dependiendo del numero del mes, obtendrás su equivalente en un String.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos.

Si te es permitido usarlo, incluso también puedes darle formato a la fecha generada por el `Calendar` con un `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
private int annio;
private int mes;
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();

public String getMes() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(c1.getTime());
}

// Este método es un método de prueba para que veas el funcionamiento.
// El único que necesitas es el método getMes()
public void metodoDePrueba() {
    annio = 2018;
    mes = 01;
    c1.set(annio, mes, 1); // ajusta la fecha a 2018-01-01
    String nombreDeMes = getMes();
    System.out.println("El nombre del mes es: " + nombreDeMes);
}
```

Resultado:

```
El nombre del mes es: enero
```

Si necesitas el nombre del mes con su primera letra en mayúscula:

```
public String getMes() {
    String mes = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(c1.getTime());
    return mes.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + mes.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una función mas sencilla, y convirtiendo ya el String a mayúsculas.

```
   public static String obtenerEtiquetaMesEspanol(Calendar fecha) {
        Month mes = LocalDate.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(fecha.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()).getMonth();
        return mes.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, new Locale("es", "ES")).toUpperCase();
    }
```